# How to use Tref in a SVG file?

Tags: svg, text, href, xlink

I tried that code but "The text to be referenced to" is never displayed on the screen, maybe it's because xlink is deprecated; would you know how to update that code to make it working ? Or what function should I use instead of xlink:href ? 
Thank you very much in advance :)

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
    <text id="Textref">
    The text to be referenced to
    </text>
    </defs>

    <text x="20" y="20" font-size="30" fill="#9d1d20" >
    Inline text
    </text>

    <text x="20" y="40" font-size="30" fill="red" style="text-decoration:underline;">
    <tref xlink:href="#Textref"/>
    </text>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tref` tag may not be supported by your browser. You would need a `use` tag:

```html
<svg width="500" height="500"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
    <text id="Textref">
    The text to be referenced to
    </text>
    </defs>

    <text x="20" y="20" font-size="30" fill="#9d1d20" >
    Inline text
    </text>

    <use  x="20" y="40" href="#Textref" font-size="30" fill="red" style="text-decoration:underline;" />
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

tref has been [dropped from SVG 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/changes.html#text) and no current browser supports it. Just put the text inline wherever you want it.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%">
 
    <text x="20" y="20" font-size="30" fill="#9d1d20" >
    Inline text
    </text>

    <text x="20" y="40" font-size="30" fill="red" style="text-decoration:underline;">
    The text to be referenced to
    </text>
    </svg>
```